# Shuffle vector of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, random, c++14

Consider a `vector<vector<int> > Vec`.

I want to shuffle the `int` values in each `vector<int>` within Vec and also perform shuffle on `vector< vector<int> >`.

How do I do this in C++?

My main aim is to randomize a matrix of integers, which I have implemented using `vector<vector<int> > Vec`.

Currently, I am trying to do this:

```
unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

for(int i=0;i<Vec.size();i++) {
    shuffle(Vec[i].begin(), Vec[i].end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
}
shuffle(Vec.begin(),Vec.end()); 
// gives an error: 
cluster.cpp:36:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘shuffle(std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator, std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator)’
```

Comment: What error? Should we guess?

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>` and use `std::shuffle()` (qualified name)?

Comment: Yes I did include them.

Comment: You appear to be using the same seed for each *row*. Also you don't supply a radom engine in your last call to `std::shuffle`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `shuffle` operation to randomly shuffle elements in an array. So you can use this twice to randomize the array. However, the issue it leaves is that numbers are shuffled in a row, and rows are also shuffled. This isn't a totally random shuffling as constraints still exist.

To get truly random shuffling, I suggest that you copy the matrix into a 1D vector, shuffle that vector and then reshape it as a matrix.

The code to shuffle a vector is as follows

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

auto engine = std::default_random_engine{};
std::shuffle(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector), engine);
```

Comment: If speed is important to you, you could also implement your 2d vector as a 1d vector with an address scheme of [a][b] = [a*TotalRowSize+b] so that you don't have to copy the entire matrix to a 1D vector to shuffle it, and then copy it all back. That assumes the rows are all the same size.

Comment: @RyanP And it's also way faster, since you have guaranteed continuous storage.

Comment: @vsoftco : I don't understand what you mean by your comment. A vector of vectors will also have continuous storage. The only reason RyanP's solution will be faster is that it avoids the overhead of copying from a 2D vector to a 1D vector.

Comment: @therainmaker No, a vector of vectors will have pointers that are store contiguously, each pointer pointing to a row. However, there's no guarantee at all (and usually it's not the case) that the memory allocating for each row is adjacent. Basically a `vector<vector<T>>` is a sophisticated wrapper around `T**`.

Comment: @vsoftco Thanks a lot. I didn't know that was the case.